# How does the variance-covariance matrix change when I create a linear combination of two variables?

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, covariance-matrix

Suppose I have four normal r.v (X,Y,W,Z) and the variance-covariance matrix is know. If I create a new r.v J=aX+bY (a and b are scalar), what is the new variance-covariance matrix?
Thank you

Comment: I mean, the variance-covariance matrix of (J,W,Z)

Comment: This question has been answered on a very great number of threads on this site, but it's hard to find the answers with a site search.  For a duplicate I chose a thread that clearly asks (and answers) the same question.

Answer (score 2):

$$\mbox{var}(ax + by) = a^2\mbox{var}(x) + b^2\mbox{var}(y) + 2ab \mbox{cov}(x, y)$$

for $x, y$ not mutually independent,

$$\mbox{cov}(ax_1 + by_1, ax_2 + by_2) = a^2 \mbox{cov}(x_1, x_2) + b^2 \mbox{cov}(y_1, y_2) + ab \left( \mbox{cov}(x_1, y_2) + \mbox{cov}(x_2, y_1 )\right)$$

Comment: I know this, but I've asked about the covariance matrix..

Comment: @Andrea it's fairly straightforward, but I added it anyway.